# get Drop down option on product view page from a multipal select custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, multiselect-attribute, drop-downs

I am working on magento 1.9, I have created a multiple selection attribute from back-end and deploy it on attribute sets, I want users to choose a time slots between 4 or 5 slots, like, there will be options 08:00 Am, 10:00 AM, 12:00PM, And so on, and user will choose appropriate time slot from all these.

The problem is i am working with virtual products as like services. so i don't want to go to the configurable or bundle way, i want a drop-down with these slots on my product page. i tried getting attribute value on select option but every time i do so i get only a drop-down not options and nor values

[image]
[image]

Any Suggestions will be appreciated

Lalit

Comment: you can use custom options for this

Comment: @GopalPatel can you please assist me how to do that?

Comment: refer http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html

Comment: @GopalPatel thank You so much,As i understand, it seems like i have to put it on every product individually?

Comment: Yes , But if you have large number of product then you can set it programmatically

Comment: almost every product on my catalog shares time slot, is there any way to do it through attributes? or any substitute other then custom options. because it seem like a lengthy and inappropriate way.

Comment: yes its lengthy process but not inappropriate because custom option are use for this purpose only. As i said you can create custom options programmatically so its one time process for you

Comment: @GopalPatel thanks for your suggestion, Can you post your answer as 'how to add custom options on catalog products of same attribute groups pragmatically'

Answer (score 1):

Create custom.php in root folder and place below code. **Run `custom.php` through command line because it will take time to run.**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

function getOptions($product){

    $slotes=$product->getAttributeText('time_slot'); //your attribute code ex. time_slot
    $slotes=explode(" ",$slotes);
    $options=array();
    foreach ($slotes as $key => $value) {
        $options[]=array(
            'title' => $value,
            'price' =>$product->getPrice,
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'sort_order' => '1'
        )
    }
    return $options;
} 

foreach ($products as $product) {
    //echo $product->getId(); //print product id
    $option = array(
        'title' => 'custom option title',
        'type' => 'drop_down', // could be drop_down ,checkbox , multiple
        'is_require' => 1,
        'sort_order' => 0,
        'values' => getOptions($product)
    );
    $optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();
    $product->setHasOptions(1);
    $optionInstance->addOption($option);
    $optionInstance->setProduct($product);
    $product->save();
    //break; //try on one product
}
```